# Deleting build dependency packages in Debian 9

Tags: bash, compilation, debian, package, apt

I have a script to compile several programs of a LEMP server (nginx, php, openssl, etc ...), I would like to know what packages I could delete after finishing with the compilations.

I leave the code fragments where I install and clean packages inside the script.

## Package installation

```
    # TODO: check this: Packages that can be deleted after the script is finished.

    apt-get -y install libxau-dev libxdmcp-dev xorg-sgml-doctools \
    libexpat1-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl \
    docbook-xml needrestart autoconf \
    automake m4 bison \
    build-essential g++ pkg-config \
    autotools-dev libtool expect \
    libcunit1-dev x11proto-core-dev file \
    libenchant-dev libjemalloc-dev gnu-standards \
    autoconf-archive g++-multilib gcc-multilib \
    libstdc++-6-dev gcc-6-locales \
    g++-6-multilib valgrind valgrind-mpi \
    valkyrie gcj-jdk flex \
    tk-dev libc-ares-dev

    # TODO: check this: Important packages that must be installed.

    apt-get -y install coreutils binutils uuid-dev wget \
    mcrypt libmcrypt-dev cython \
    perl libpcre3 libpcre3-dev  \
    libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev \
    libtiffxx5 libjpeg62-turbo-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev \
    libjansson-dev \
    libgmp-dev libev-dev libevent-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev libgdbm-dev libdb-dev \
    libsystemd-dev libspdylay-dev \
    libaio-dev libncurses5-dev \
    libunistring-dev libunbound-dev \
    trousers libidn2-0 \
    libicu-dev libltdl-dev libpspell-dev libreadline-dev \
    libc6-dev libc-dbg libpam0g-dev libmsgpack-dev libstemmer-dev libbsd-dev \
    gettext debian-keyring liblinear-tools liblinear-dev \
    libdbi-perl libboost-all-dev rsync net-tools libdbd-mysql-perl \
    re2c libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev qt4-qmake libqt4-dev \
    libssl-dev golang python-dev python3-dev python-setuptools
```

## Package cleaning

```
apt-get -y remove libxau-dev libxdmcp-dev xorg-sgml-doctools \
libexpat1-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl \
docbook-xml needrestart autoconf \
automake m4 bison \
build-essential g++ pkg-config \
autotools-dev libtool expect \
libcunit1-dev x11proto-core-dev file \
libenchant-dev libjemalloc-dev gnu-standards \
autoconf-archive g++-multilib gcc-multilib \
libstdc++-6-dev gcc-6-locales \
g++-6-multilib valgrind valgrind-mpi \
valkyrie gcj-jdk flex \
tk-dev libc-ares-dev
```

apt-get -y autoremove
apt-get clean

I guess it's a good practice to do this kind of cleaning, I could clean all the packages that their names end in -dev. Or could this affect something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends.

If you are creating one or several Debian packages by your `compiling`, using proper packaging tools and workflows), and afterwards install them (via `dpkg`), these packages will contain dependency information (some automatically detected - like which dynamic libraries are required to run/load the generated binaries; others manually added during the packaging process).
These dependencies will then ensure that all the required packages will stay installed.

However, if you just compile some random software `superserver` and install it via `make install`, the system has no way of knowing that your binary `/usr/local/bin/superserver` actually requires the presence of Debian packages.

When you installed some `-dev` packages to satisfy build dependencies, this might have pulled in some additional packages (typically the corresponding dynamic libraries; e.g. installing `libfoo-dev` will make sure that you also have `libfoo0` installed).
Once you have removed all packages (e.g. `libfoo-dev`) that depend on another package which has been automatically installed to satisfy these dependencies (e.g. `libfoo0`), then `apt-get -y autoremove` will automatically remove those leftovers.

So if your `superserver` depends on `libfoo0` but the system doesn't know about it, you will end up with a broken `superserver` binary.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and it's true, I have installed packages finished in -dev that install runtime libraries necessary for my compiled applications to work.

When deleting libaspell-dev and execute: php -V

/usr/local/php7/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libaspell.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory